# Preventing href to move to header after action

Tags: php

I have this code

`<a class ="hi" href='uselesslinkhere.php?page=page1&action=add&id=myid'>Add??</a>`

Whenever a person clicks on this button, the link will act as if its a href=#.
Will using jQuery help? and if so, how does it work?

Thank guys!

Comment: You haven't closed the quotes around your href

Comment: <a href="yourlink">Click me </a>

Comment: Hi sorry opps, completed the code now.

Comment: Are you firing a javascript event when it's clicked? If so return false from that click event, otherwise I don't understand why you have a href there in the first place if you don't want people to follow the url

Comment: I didn't understand your question, what is your problem exactly?  It is acting in that manner(replacing the url with "#") and you are not sure if it is using jQuery or it should it act in that manner and asking if jQuery can do that?

Comment: Hmm, Im using a $_GET action to get the item's ID as im using a query to output a few items, and based on the item ID, it will be added to the session. Now that you mentioned it, i could fire a javascript event to do this too. I.E when someone clicks on the link the user will be redirected to the action, which is still within my index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a onclick event on anchor tag and stop page from following the href. Then change the content on your page through jQuery as you like and add the desired url through history.

```
<a class ="hi" onclick="loadPage(event,'uselesslinkhere.php?page=page1&action=add&id=myid')" href='uselesslinkhere.php?page=page1&action=add&id=myid'>Add??</a>

var loadPage = function(event,pageUrl){

        event.preventDefault();


        if(history && history.pushState)
            {
                history.pushState(null,null,pageUrl);
            }

       return false;
    }
```

Comment: i saw your previous answer, an am following that now! will update if it works! thanks :)

Comment: sure, according to what i understood from your question, you want to implement ajax driven page rather than a page reload. So i gave solution based on that.